# Convert file or directory to symbolic link and preserve permissions

Tags: linux, bash, chown

I have `/home/eric/public_html` with `drwxr-x---  eric:nobody` as the mod and ownership.

I login with `eric` so I cannot recreate this folder without root access, since `eric` is not part of the `nobody` group.

I want to replace my `public_html` with a symbolic link (i.e. `ln -s ~/git/project/src ~/public_html`) but if I do that, my new `public_html` ends us without the correct permissions.

Is there a trick to get around this without contacting my admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly by doing the following:

1. Copy everything from `~/git/project/src` into `~/public_html`
2. `mv ~/git/project/src ~/git/project/src2` to get it out of the way
3. `mv ~/public_html ~/git/project/src`
4. finally link it back: `ln -s ~/git/project/src ~/public_html`

The idea is to keep the original `public_html` directory because it has the correct owner/permissions, but reuse it as the link target.

Comment: I see, since what I am missing is that the permissions are not of the link but of the target?

Comment: @ericosg Yeah, symbolic links themselves appear as `lrwxrwxrwx` because only the target permissions are relevant.